# Can't load images of React app when the app is loaded on a path, not the root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have created a React application that runs well on Localhost. However, when I try to run it on a website I get issues. The images aren't showing. I think the main issue is that the place where I want to load the React application is on a path of an existing website.

https://app.stage.example.be/leads/bsure is where I want to load my React app.

However, the images are still pointing towards the root of the website, https://app.stage.example.be/, and thus are not shown.

[image]

This should be /leads/bsure/bsure-logo.jpg, but it still points towards the root:

[image]

**Things I have tried:**

I have changed the PUBLIC_URL in .env.production.local. When I do a log on the console it shows me that the public url is indeed the right one:

[image]

[image]

I have also changed the basename of the Router to make sure it matches the website.

[image]

Does someone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: Don't use an absolute URL? Consider trying a relative one like `./bsure-logo.svg` instead?

Comment: Will those links still point toward my images when I am in a subroute like https://app.stage.example.be/leads/bsure/step1/step?

Comment: The images in the bundle file are on the same level as my index.html.

Comment: If you use an absolute URL like `/` it will point to `app.stage.example.be/` use a relative URL like `./` to point to a directory relative to the current page.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: It only works when the URL ends in a slash. When I remove the slash at the end the images still don't laod

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates this img tag?

Comment: _"unfortunately it didn't work"_ - please share this attempt